# Obtain object level concurrency - JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am new to multi-threading and need a little help in object level locking. Thanks in advance.

I have two classes say Person and Attendance and 2 methods (setAttendance, getAttendance) in each of the classes such that method of Class Person calls the specific method of Class Attendance. Both the methods in class Attendance are synchronized.
I want to obtain concurrency in such a way that if method 1 is in progress, method 2 cannot be called by the same user. I want to obtain object level locking and want to  create the object on session level, i.e. obtain concurrency on session level(i.e. methods are locked for 1 user but if the web application is accessed by some other user, he can access the method if it was not locked by him)
Here is the code snippet:

```
class Person{

    //method 1
    public void setAttendance(){
        //call setAttendance method of class Ateendance
     }

     //method 2
    public void getAttendance(){
        //call getAttendance method of class Ateendance
     }
}

// methods of class Attendance are called from Person class

Class Attendance{

   // method 1
   void synchronized setAttendance(String str){

    }

   // method 2
   String synchronized getAttendance(){
     return "";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Attendance` two methods define with `synchronized` is enough. This means if the object's method is invoking by one thread, all other threads can't invoke `synchronized` code. So it means a person can't invoke the other method with another thread.

For another person, he can't invoke the attendance object too. So you need to create a new attendance object for the second person.

Comment: thanks, but my main concern is regarding object creation only. How to create and define object such that the object is same for a user in the session but a new object is created for another user

Comment: You can create new attendance when another user send the first httprequest or create new session. Even more, you can add attribute `owner` in Attendance.

Comment: Also, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html